# Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x0a 0x4c Error

Tags: image, opencv, jpeg

I'm trying to import a bunch of images of .jpeg file format. 
However I'm getting the error

`Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x0a 0x4c`

Now, I know `0x89 0x50` is how .png files start. But I can't understand what `0x0a 0x4c` represents.

I also ran the `file image001.jpeg` command on the terminal and it gave me

`JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01`.

Also, when I'm importing these group of images, this error is thrown for different files each time, not the same ones. So, I guess it isn't an issue of the file being corrupted.

If it helps, the image files were generated and saved on the hard disk through the `imwrite()` function of `opencv`.

Thanks

Using `ImageMagick`, the following verbose output is obtained.

```
Image: /Users/deathstroke/Desktop/lipRead/VidTIMIT/mwbt0/video/sx383/roi081.jpeg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 68x39+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 2652
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 223 (0.87451)
      mean: 139.207 (0.54591)
      standard deviation: 44.1822 (0.173263)
      kurtosis: 0.798663
      skewness: -1.01178
      entropy: 0.942718
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 159 (0.623529)
      mean: 87.1161 (0.341632)
      standard deviation: 33.4156 (0.131041)
      kurtosis: -0.162594
      skewness: -0.485596
      entropy: 0.955489
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 249 (0.976471)
      mean: 73.9367 (0.289948)
      standard deviation: 43.7079 (0.171403)
      kurtosis: 2.38585
      skewness: 1.43844
      entropy: 0.917047
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 249 (0.976471)
      mean: 100.087 (0.392496)
      standard deviation: 40.7392 (0.159761)
      kurtosis: 2.09684
      skewness: 0.445232
      entropy: 0.938418
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 68x39+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 95
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2016-04-15T23:19:32+06:00
    date:modify: 2016-04-15T23:19:32+06:00
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
    signature: d3f2c14b57043efd4edbf719dfe769aded504df16c5b9fc8ee436d7551993221
  Artifacts:
    filename: /Users/deathstroke/Desktop/lipRead/VidTIMIT/mwbt0/video/sx383/roi081.jpeg
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 1.81KB
  Number pixels: 2.65K
  Pixels per second: 265KB
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.009
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86_64 2016-03-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: If you are on Linux, you probably have ImageMagick installed. In which case you could try examining an *"unhappy"* file with `identify -verbose unhappy.jpg`. You could also try re-encoding it with `convert unhappy.jpg hopefullyHappy.jpg`.

Comment: No, I'm using Mac OSX Operating System. Is there an ImageMagick equivalent of OSX too?

Comment: There is. You would find it easiest to install with `homebrew`. You would go to http://brew.sh and copy and paste the Ruby one-liner into your Terminal. Then do `brew install imagemagick`

Comment: Or you can Email me an unhappy picture and I'll try it for you.

Comment: So, the thing is... The 'unhappy' images don't stay the same... if I run the script multiple times.. the images which throw this error are always different.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, please have a look at the edited post. I've added the output from the ImageMagick command. It seems that the problematic file is jpeg itself, though

Comment: And if you re-encode an unhappy image does it then work? `convert unhappy.jpg re-encoded.jpg`

Comment: Nope. Still the same issue.. I ran a script to convert all images. That script also gave the 'not a jpeg file' error for some of the images. And again, those images were different when I ran the script a second time.

Comment: I know this an old thread, but for whoever comes across the same issue, this is caused by so-called trailer data. The error says "starts with" but it really is referring to data that comes _after_ the EOI (end of image) marker. Up to and including that marker, the JPEG image is valid, and according to JPEG/JFIF specification there should not be any data after the EOI marker, but some software does store extra information there. For example there are AFCP trailers (starting with bytes 0x41 0x58) using the AXS File Concatenation protocol for storing IPTC press and newspaper tags.

Answer (score 2):

A JPEG Stream starts with an SOI marker FF D8. A JFIF file follows that with an APP0 marker FF E0.

It is entirely possible that you have a valid JPEG stream embedded somewhere in your data and that some applications are skipping over the non-jpeg data until they reach the SOI marker while other are puking on extraneous data.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an ImageMagick equivalent of OSX too?

What does this question mean?  Imagemagick does not provide any OS. But there are a Imagemagick versions that do work on Mac OSX. Imagemagick provides one binary version for El Capitan ONLY. See [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx)

But you can install from source or better install IM 6 or 7 from Homebrew or IM 7 from Mac Ports. The way I go about it, is to install all my delegates from MacPorts and install Imagemagick from source. See http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31844 and http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix